# Why do people love nature?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, experimental-psychology, psychology

I wonder why we feel happy and comfortable when seeing the view of trees, green plants and flowers. Why do we admire sea, waves, fishes inside pure water and sun set? why do we love seeing the view of sky, moon and stars? Why people love nature even it is not real like a Picture on a computer?

To be more clear, People love seeing sea but the don't feel the same when they see a cup of water although they both are water.

Is it pure psychological reason? or There are some other biological reasons or chemistry of the brain?

Thank you very much,

Comment: Good question, although fundamentally the answer is "we don't know yet".

Comment: I dont have the time to provide a long answer but its worth checking out the biophilia hypothesis (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biophilia_hypothesis) which provides an evolutionary explanation for why this may occur. I don't know much about how good the evidence is for this, although this only provides an evolutionary explanation rather than a biological/psychological (proximal) one.

Comment: Because those who hated it could not live with it. That which supports life becomes attractive. It's a bit like the Stockholm syndrome of nature. As a rule of thumb, remember one thing: Everything we are, have, or are not or don't have relates to our survival, to evolution. For example, take pain. The amount of pain you feel anywhere correlates with how relevant that body part is for you or our species, and how likely it is that you can avoid injuries by feeling pain. We lost hair because clothes are better adjustable. We have some hair to deter bugs or to signal health to the other sex.

Comment: Perhaps we don't. Perhaps we love new experiences, a refreshing scene, the culture of vacation, or the need to project a picture of success on social media. Perhaps one would dislike a forest if they were living in it or they would "feel happy" visiting a metropolis. In addition, perhaps most of nature is not comforting and enjoyable, but rather people go to those parts of nature that are perceived as beautiful. Perhaps it is sociological. (I do like nature though :D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People love nature because truth, nature/natural experience, and reality go hand in hand. Nature provides serenity, beauty, and calm. Our **world of experience** is what gives us, and provides for, life. Ultimately and fundamentally, the integrated extensiveness (and sensibility) of being and experience go hand in hand, as the self represents, forms, and experiences a comprehensive approximation of experience in general by combining conscious and unconscious experience. In fact, we always begin with typical/ordinary and common experience in establishing physical fundamentals/truths. Experience is the best teacher, and the creations of our thought that replace nature/natural experience, such as TV and mirrors, *maximally* **reduce** the integrated extensiveness of space/our experience. A true, extensive, integrated, and natural balance of being and experience is best. Balance and completeness go hand in hand. If we walk away from reality, reality walks away from us.

Comment: Do you have any sources? Are you aware of any scientific literature? This reads like speculation and personal philosophy.